# Select_tag rails, display value dynamically before submit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html-select

I have a form showing some available banks I can choose, using a select_tag.
The selected bank is stored in params[:bank] when I submit the form

What I want to do is to dynamically show information about the selected bank before submitting. Basically, if I chose "Bank 1", I want to display bank 1 information. If I select Bank 2, I want to display bank 2 information. And when I am happy, I submit.

Here is my code

```
<%= form_tag final_payments_path, method: :get do %>

  <%= select_tag "bank", options_from_collection_for_select(Bank.active, "id", "name") %>

  <%= button_tag( class: "btn-continue-displayed mt-3") do %>
   <i class="fas fa-caret-left"></i><p>Approve</p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How can I dynamically find the selected option before submitting and display the information?

My first step was to add onchange: "alert(this.value)" on my select tag. It works and shows the id. If I change and put

```
 options_from_collection_for_select(Bank.active, "IBAN", "name")
```

it shows an alert with the IBAN. Which is a good start.

Is there a way I can put 3 elements (id, IBAN and SWIFT) in the value instead of only one?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: The only way to accomplish this is through some type of Javascript. If you show us what you tried then you will be more likely to get an answer.

Comment: I've made some researches and maybe found a way to do it, but I don't know if that's possible and the syntax for it if it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find bank id via js:

```
$('#select_tag_id').on('change', function () {
    let bank_id = $(this).val();
});
```

`bank_id` will contain id of selected bank.

routes.rb:

```
  get "/selected_bank" => 'your_controller#show_info'
```

Then:

```
$('#select_tag_id').on('change', function () {
      let bank_id = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
          data: {bank_id: bank_id},
          url: '/selected_bank',
          type: 'GET'
      });
  });
```

Your controller:

```
def show_info
  @bank = Bank.find(params[:bank_id])
  respond_to { |format| format.js }
end
```

_info.html.erb:

```
<div class="info">
  <p>
    Id:
    <%= @bank.id %>
  </p>
  <p>
    Name:
    <%= @bank.name %>
  </p>
</div>
```

show_info.js.erb:

```
$('.some-class-on-page').html("<%= j(render 'info') %>");
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I had the bank id already. I just don't know how to find the bank with this id and show its information as I can't put ruby code inside my js

Comment: But your comment gave me another id. I will iterate on all my banks, create a div having the id as a classname, and I will use javascript to remove "d-none".
Thanks :)

Comment: @Jessicascn You can use ajax to pass `bank_id` to controller action. In controller, find bank from database and place it in instance variable. Then create `action_name.js.erb`, which will render partial with passed variable.

Comment: @Jessicascn Look at the changes in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! perfect, I was confused on how  to use ajax here

Comment: @Jessicascn U r welcome. Contact if you have any difficulties.